# Retrieve string between two string delimiters using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have been working on this for a little while now and can't seem to figure it out. I have a file containing a bunch of lines all structured like the one below meaning each line starts with "!" and has three separators "`<DIV>`".

```
!the<DIV>car<DIV>drove down the<DIV>road off into the distance
```

I am interested in retrieving the last string "road off into the distance" I can't seem to get it to work. Below I have listed the current code I have.

```
while($line = <INFILE>) {
    $line =~ /<SEP>{3}(.*)/;
    print $1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
@b = $a =~ /^!(.*?)<DIV>(.*?)<DIV>(.*?)<DIV>(.*)/
```

will split the string into a list, and you can then extract the 4th element with

```
$b[3]
```

If you really want only the last one, do this instead:

```
($text) = $a =~ /^!.*<DIV>(.*)/
```

Comment: OP asks for 'everything past last <DIV>' so it wouldn't need the leading `!` for that, even though the context has it. The requirement is not clear (do lines w/o `^!` count?), and I like coding the full behavior (upvoted), but sticking to the minimal problem statement (no `^!`) should not be worse and I'd suggest to add it for completeness?

Comment: @zdim agreed, will edit tomorrow as it's rather hard to edit on an iPad

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether you insist on regex or simply didn't think of else, but `split` will nicely do this

```
$text = (split '<DIV>', $str)[-1];
```

If you regularly have such repeating patterns `split` may well be better for the job than a pure regex. (Split also uses full regular expressions in its pattern, of course.)

**ADDED**

All this can be done directly, if you simply only need to pull the last thing from each line:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file;
my @text = map { (split '<DIV>')[-1] } <$fh>;
close $fh;
print "$_\n" for @text;
```

The `split` by default uses `$_`, which inside the map is the current element processed.  For lines without a `<DIV>` this returns the whole line.  A file handle in the list context serves all lines as a list; the list context is imposed by `map` here.

In case you want all text between delimiters you can do

```
my @rlines = map { [ split '<DIV>' ] } <$fh>;
```

where `[ ]` takes a reference to the list returned by `split` and thus `@rlines` contains references to arrays, each with text in between `<DIV>`s on a line. The leading `!` is there though and to drop it a little more processing is needed.

Of course, for the map block you can use `{ (/.*<DIV>(.*)/)[0] }` from [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison)'s answer for a single match, or modify the regex a little to catch'em all.

If performance is a factor then that's a little different question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple substitution could work too:

```
while(<DATA>){
chomp;
my $text = (s/.*<DIV>//g, $_);
say $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex which answers your question:

```
my $match= '';
while($line = <INFILE>) {
 ($match) = $line =~/.*<DIV>(.*)/; 
}
print $match, "\n";
```